# ADO.NET DeadLock

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net, deadlock

I'm experiencing an intermittent deadlock situation with following (simplified) code.

```
DataSet my_dataset = new DataSet()
SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand();

sql_command.Connection = <valid connection>
sql_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sql_command.CommandText = 'SELECT * FROM MyView ORDER BY 1'

SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_command);

sql_command.Connection.Open();

data_adapter.Fill(my_dataset);

sql_command.Connection.Close();
```

The error I get is:

> Transaction (Process ID 269) was
>   deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as
>   the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

As I understand it, simply filling a DataSet via the ADO.Net .Fill() command shouldn't create a lock on the database. 
And, it would appear from the error message that the lock is owned by another process.
The View I'm querying against has select statements only, but it does join a few table together.

- Can a view that is only going a select statement be affected by locked records?
- Can/Does ADO.Net .Fill() Lock Records?
- Assuming I need to fill a DataSet, is there a way to do so that would avoid potential data locks?

SQL Server 2005 (9.0.4035)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A select query with joins can indeed cause a deadlock.  One way to deal with this is to do the query in a SqlTransaction using Snapshot Isolation.

```
using(SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
{
    // Query goes here.
}
```

A deadlock can occur because it locks each table being joined one after another before performing the join.  If another query has a lock on a table that the other query needs to lock, and vice versa, there is a dead lock.  With [Snapshot Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130975.aspx) queries that just read from tables do not lock them.  Integrity is maintained because the read is actually done from a snapshot of the data at the time the transaction started.

This can have a negative impact on performance, though, because of the overhead of having to produce the snapshots.  Depending on the application, it may be better to not use snapshot isolation and instead, if a query fails do to a deadlock, wait a little while and try again.

It might also be better to try to find out why the deadlocks are occurring and change the structure of the database and/or modify the application to prevent deadlocks.  This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) has more information.

Comment: Could you expand the information on that further? I'd be very much interested in any explanatory documents or links as to how and why this behaviour comes to pass.

Comment: ADO "Classic" has different lock levels... I'm wondering now, what is the default lock level for ADO.NET? Is the method above how I would go about "tweaking" the connection itself? Do I still have a read lock if I set the IsolationLevel to Snapshot or ReadUncommited?

Comment: The default isolation is Read Committed.  In the above method the isolation level just applies to the transaction.  You can configure the server to default to a different isolation level.  ReadUncommitted does not use locks either; it is faster but can result in less accurate data.

Comment: Does this mean that if I don't implicitly "BeginTransaction" for my query, ado.net is wrapping my query is a transaction anyway?

Comment: You do have to explicitly begin the transaction or no transaction will occur.

Comment: If I DON'T begin a transaction, what kind of lock will I end up with? Thanks so much for you help BTW!

Comment: If you dont begin a transaction and change the isolation level youll have the default isolation level ReadCommitted, which locks tables in the join.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

- Lower the transaction level for that query (for instance, `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited`).
- Use the `NOLOCK` hint on you query.

Answer (score 0):

It might be far off and not the solution to your problem, check other solutions first - but, we had a similar problem (a select that locks records!) that after much effort we tracked to the file/SMB layer. It seemed that under heavy load, reading files from the networked drive (SAN) got held up, creating a waiting read lock on the actual database files. This expressed as a lock on the records contained.

But this was a race condition and not reproducable without load on the drives. Oh, and it was SQL Server 2005, too.

You should be able to determine using the SQL Server included tools which transactions are deadlocking each other.